# django widgets нужно в поле добавить виджет что то типа selectmultiple, но не получается

Tags: python, django

Как лучше сделать: мне необходимо чтобы в строке я мог выбрать несколько позиций? При этом форма должна проходить валидацию. В данный момент стоит просто Select и все работает.

forms.py

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ['nazv', 'categ', 'fio', 'nach_obuch', 'konec_obuch']

    widgets = {
        'nazv': TextInput(attrs={
         'class': 'form-control',
         'placeholder': 'Номер группы',
        }),
        'categ': TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Категория',
        }),
        'fio': Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        }),
        'nach_obuch': DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'type': 'date',
        }),
        'konec_obuch': DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'type': 'date',
        }),
    }
```

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    nazv = models.CharField('нг', max_length=20)
    categ = models.CharField('кат', max_length=20)
    fio = models.ForeignKey(Ucheniki, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nach_obuch = models.DateField('Начало')
    konec_obuch = models.DateField('Конец')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazv

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/avtoschool/{self.id}'

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Список групп'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Список групп'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте select2, тиа и пример в документации есть https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/